Pre Clarkson Inequality
I am actually struggling with a seemingly totally trivial inequality.
For any non negative $a,b$ and $p > 2$:
$a^p + b^p \leq (a+b)^p$.
For natural $p$ this is obvious, but what is with the rationals or even irrationals between two integers?
The plan was to show the inequality holds for any rational $p>2$, and via continuity, it has for any real $p>2$ then.
But I have no idea how to show this.
I tried it with several functions an convexity but i failed.
I hope someone has a smooth solution.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

homogeneous, it is sufficient to prove it for $b=1$

See art of problem solving.

Yes thank you Mr. Burde

For $p>1$ and $a,b>0$ prove $a^{p}+b^{p}\le(a+b)^{p}.$
Dividing by $a^{p}$ it is enough to show $1+x^{p}\leq(1+x)^{p},\textrm{ for }0\leq x.$
For $x=0$ we have $1+0^{p}=1\leq(1+0)^{p}$ so the inequality holds in this case. Take the derivative of both sides we get $px^{p-1}$ and $p(1+x)^{p-1},$ respectively. Since $px^{p-1}\leq p(1+x)^{p-1},$ the desired inequality follows from calculus.
